# how to find increasing-decreasing trends in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to compare a dataframe's different columns with each other row by row like

```py
for (i= startday to endday)
    if(df[i]<df[i+1])
    counter=counter+1
    else
    i=endday+1
```

the goal is find increasing (or decreasing) trends(need to be consecutive)
And my data looks like this

```
df= 1 2 3 0 1 1 1
    1 1 1 1 0 1 2
    1 2 1 0 1 1 2 
    0 0 0 0 1 0 1
```

(In this example startday to endday is 7 but actually these two are unstable)

As a result i expect to find this {2,0,1,0} and i need it to work fast because my data is quite big(1.2 million). Because of the time limit I tried not to use loops (for, if etc.)

I tried the code below but couldn't find how to stop counter if condition is false

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1=df.copy()   
df2=df.copy()
bool1 = (np.less_equal.outer(startday.startday, range(1,13)) 
            & np.greater_equal.outer(endday.endday, range(1,13))
            )

bool1= np.c_[np.zeros(len(startday)),bool1].astype('bool')

bool2 = (np.less_equal.outer(startday2.startday2, range(1,13)) 
            & np.greater_equal.outer(endday2.endday2, range(1,13))
            )

bool2= np.c_[bool2, np.zeros(len(startday))].astype('bool')


df1.insert(0, 'c_False',math.pi)
df2.insert(12, 'c_False',math.pi)
#df2.head()
arr_bool = (bool1&bool2&(df1.values<df2.values))

df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.sum(arr_bool , axis=1), 
                        index=data_idx, columns=['coll'])

df_new.coll= np.select( condlist = [startday.startday > endday.endday],
                         choicelist = [-999], 
                         default = df_new.coll)
```

Comment: you can use a **df.apply(comparison_function, axis=1)** where **comparison_function** is a function that takes a row as argument

Comment: How do you get `{3,0,2,0}` from that exactly... you should look at producing a [mcve] of code... I think you're muddying the waters here - what's `startday` for instance - where does `pi` come into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add zeros at the end, then use `np.diff`, then get the first "non positive" using `argmin`:

```
(np.diff(np.hstack((df.values, np.zeros((df.values.shape[0], 1)))), axis=1) > 0).argmin(axis=1)
>> array([2, 0, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: How does 2, 0, 1, 0 represent something coming from the original DataFrame since there's no row I can find that specifically shows that sequence?